# jqgrid select box option set selected

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i am using jqgrid and i am adding a row that contains fields: textbox and selectbox.

After adding a row by selecting the age from the dropdown, when i click on this row for editing, the age dropdown list must mark the selected value by default. How to achieve this ?

This is the code showing the columns data:

```
colModel:[                          
{name:'user_id',index:'user_id',  width:150,align:"center",editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}},      
{name:'user_name',index:'user_name', width:250, align:"left",editable:true,editoptions:{size:30}},
{name: 'Age', width: 40, editable: true, formatter: 'select',
edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: age_list },   
hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }}
]
```

where 'age_list' is the array of age values in the form of a javascript array.

Comment: jqGrid really mark automatically the selected value by default in all my tests in both inline or form editing. You should post more code which you use, because the problem is sure outside of the posted code. For example which `age_list` you use? which format has the contain of the 'Age' column? How you fill the grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `edittype: 'custom'` for your column, and then you can create your own html for the control:

```
<script>
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
...
   colModel: [ 
      ... 
      {name:'price', ..., editable:true, edittype:'custom', editoptions:{custom_element: functionThatReturnsHtmlElement, custom_value: functionThatReturnsTheValueYouNeed} },
      ...
   ]
...
});
</script>
```

More details at jqGrid's documentation wiki: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editable

Comment: I could not find a way of setting a default value like as you said above: **<option ... selected>display</option>**. I tried with: **editoptions: { value: age_list, defaultValue:"2" }** but that doesn't work. I see that the first option in the dropdown is getting selected by default.

Comment: I'll edit to be more clear.  You have to use the `custom` edittype, you're not doing that yet.

Comment: what does the custom_element and custom_value indicate?

Comment: For all the details on that please follow the link to jqGrid's documentation and look at the edtittype -> custom section.  Their example is for creating an "input" element, but you can easily customize it to create a "select" element.  I would answer you directly but I'd just be copying their documentation.

Comment: By the way, i have viewed the source code of this demo page: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependendSelects2.htm  and i could get a clean solution to my problem. Exactly what i wanted in edit scenario. Still accepting your solution :)